# Why isn't View>View Settings working in ArcGIS 10 ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I am running ArcGIS 10 desktop verison with the 3d Analyst extension to view DEMs in ArcScene. I want to view the DEM from a specific xyz location, which should be achievable using the View Settings dialogue box in the View menu. When I click on View>View Settings nothing happens except the menu closes. I can't find any hint of why this isn't working in the ArcGIS help, forums or blogs. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I would like to ask you how is the process to register HorizonDial.ocx, I'm new in ArcScene and I have the same error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it.

You probably got HorizonDial.ocx unregistered.

Try to register it again using:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\ThirdParty\bin\HorizonDial.ocx"
```

On x64 system use regsvr32 from c:\Windows\SysWOW64, not the default one from c:\Windows\System32.